# How can I send multipage articles to Instapaper quickly and easily?

Tags: instapaper

I want to be able to send multiple page articles (eg cracked.com) to Instapaper or ReaditLater quickly and easily, is there a solution for this? I have tried everything I can find on Google for it but nothing seems to work reliably!

Comment: I think it depends on the site. I know for sure that for newyorker.com and newyorktimes.com this works just fine, so I assume it has more to do with the way the pages are constructed (markup structure, links, etcetera) than with the app itself.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your question, but the Firefox extension for ReadItLater has a "batch" function. When it is turned on, you can just click on all the links you want to save to ReadItLater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is now possible](http://blog.instapaper.com/post/18556429689).

> The new bookmarklet now also supports automatic saving of every page in multi-page articles.

Comment: Neat although doesn't work for Cracked -- the main offender.

Answer (score 2):

ReadItLater has been supporting Multipage for quite some time (atleast over a year as i remember). Instapaper added support recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Safari's Reader Function, select it and scroll to the end until all pages are finished.

Then send it to Instapaper mail via your [extras](http://www.instapaper.com/extras)

For example, try it on this article: http://www.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,2036683_2037183_2037185-1,00.html